# Smooth Player Movement?

Tags: python, game-engine

So im trying to make a movement script and i want it to have a max speed and min speed iv'e tried using the `object.applyForce((0, 10, 0))` but that just keeps adding up the speed of the object.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to have acceleration and inertia, make sure to use this method:

- Add a property to your player called speed(or something that will be easy to understand for what it is used.
- Set it to Integer, leave it's value `0`.
- Add `property` sensor and `keyboard` sensor to your object. Add that key in keyboard sensor, which will make your character move. Make it true level triggering and set frequency to your own wish- the bigger frequency, the slower character will accelerate. Connect to `and` controller.
- Select interval in `property` sensor. Select your 'speed' property in it. Make it's interval from 0 up to 10 or bigger number. Enable true level triggering and set frequency identical to the one used in `keyboard` sensor.
- Connect also `property` sensor to and controller.
- Add `property` actuator. Select your 'speed' property it. Make it `Add`. In bottom input type `1` or `+1`.
- Now repeat this again, but make sure tu use different interval(if previous was from 1 up to 10, thn now it is from 11 up to 20 etc.) You can play around with the add property and frequency.
- Now do the same, but invert. Repeat the same proccess, but make sure you use invert in `keyboard` sensor and the last interval's biggest number is bigger than in positive keyboard use(if previously your biggest numbers were `21` - `30` and add property always was +1, than use `31` in last property, but anyway, if you add more in that property, make sure to make also that number much bigger than previous(positive keyboard press).
- Add `property` sensors with intervals(as ymuch as you wish). Use different intervals in each. Connect them to `and` controllers and to `motion` actuators. Make each motion actuator move a bit faster than previous.

Now you should have working acceleration and inertia. Sorry for long text:D If you need, ask me for .blend example here!;)

**EDIT**
Here is .blend:
[DOWNLOAD](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bybkedsj7a8cwzy/AccInertiaExample.blend?dl=0)

Comment: Yeah i'd like to see the .blend cause i got kinda lost xD

Comment: OK! I will edit a bit later!

Comment: P.S. It is non-python

Comment: the download does not work.

Comment: Works for me- just click on it or go here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/bybkedsj7a8cwzy/AccInertiaExample.blend?dl=0